How can I scroll a part of the screen to see some options without the content on the sides moving? (in language C)
I am currently developing a cookie clicker-type game using Processing, and I'm facing a challenge with the user interface. In the section where I have multiple buttons for purchasing different structures, the design requires vertical scrolling to access all of the buttons. However, there are various elements on the right and left sides of the screen that I do not want to move or be affected by the scrolling.
My main goal is to create a scrolling area that only affects the buttons and their corresponding information while keeping the surrounding elements fixed in place. As I am relatively new to game development and programming, I’m unsure about the best approach to achieve this functionality.
If anyone has experience with Processing or similar frameworks, or if you can point me in the right direction regarding how to implement fixed and scrollable areas in my game, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Your assistance would be invaluable to me as I navigate this learning process.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Is this a text game or GUI?

The controlP5 library has a scrollableList control.  Look under File/Examples/Contributed Libraries/ControlP5/controllers/ControlP5ScrollableList for an example.

@apodidae Sounds like you could post that as the answer to the question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Lundin I'm waiting to see if the developer can use it.

@PauDeAlbaViñas Can you please add a few more clarifications so it's easier for everyone to contribute ? 1. The description mainly mentions Processing, however the title and tag mentions C: are you using the Processing language and IDE or C ? Can you please post a simplified snippet of your attempt to code the scrolling area ? Thank you.
